# Docker wont build anymore after accedently trying to delete windowsfilter folder

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, windows-server-2016

C:\ProgramData\Docker\Windowsfilter took up most of the space on the server so i tryed to delete it, couple of things got deleted but 90% of the folder cant be deleted due to "Access Denied" message (im full admin).

now when trying to build a microsoft/iss docker image, it failes no matter what im doing:

> docker : failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1:
>   output: GetFileAttributesEx
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\bc1cc61881c347f8e666028fbff83c46f8e1f5550e47385749b0c1b683bb2289\UtilityVM\Files\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows
>   Defender\Scans\History\CacheManager\01D5215E-0000-0000-0000-100000000000-0.bin:
>   The system cannot find the file specified. At E:\bauen.ps1:5 char:1
>   + docker build --tag iistest . --file .\iisonly.dockerfile
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (failed to regis...file specified.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

cant get it working again, is there a way t o repair docker? or to clean the windowsfilter folder? found nothing on documention site.
also the commands:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

do not clean up everything that got build etc. as we can see by that error message.

running windows server 2016, trying to build microsoft/iis image

Comment: This [GitHub thread](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26873) has some suggestions.

Comment: thanks  @BenH. I tryed the ZAP tool beore, but i forgot to stop the docker service so it didnt cleaned up properly. Now it works again. thanks and +rep